# labels on geom_boxplot for DAUTONSA dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I am trying to put the proper labels (2011-2017) for my boxplot:

```
monthly_sales <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robintux/Datasets4StackOverFlowQuestions/master/Monthly_Sales_2011-2017.csv"
                          ,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


# BoxPlot 
ggplot(monthly_sales, aes( x = year, y = DAUTONSA, color = as.factor(year))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 2011:2017, labels = as.character(2011:2017))
```

the result is

[image: Boxplot for DAUTONSA by year]

the label for each boxplot should be year (2011-2017)

Comment: the original source of the (complete) data is: [DAUTONSA](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DAUTONSA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem: make the variable 'year' character when you call ggplot(aes):

```
monthly_sales <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robintux/Datasets4StackOverFlowQuestions/master/Monthly_Sales_2011-2017.csv"
                          ,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


# BoxPlot 
ggplot(monthly_sales, aes(x = as.character(year), y = DAUTONSA, color = as.factor(year))) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(2011:2017))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes , vthat's precisely what I'm looking to get . thx Harro.

Comment: If that is what you were looking for, could you please upvote and approve the answer?